# How to Add Records in a 0:0..N in Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

We have a MS SQL SERVER table structure like such:

```
Table Org {
  Id Int
  Name Varchar(50)
}

Table Request {
  Id Int
  Name Varchar(50)
  OrgId int Not Null
}
```

Our Models look like this:

```
public class Org
{
     public int Id { get; set;}
     public string Name { get; set;}
     public List<Request> Requests { get; set;}
}

public class Request
{
     public int Id { get; set;}
     public string Name { get; set;}
     public int OrgId { get; set;}
}
```

And our configuration is like such:

```
public class RequestConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Request>
{
    public RequestConfiguration()
    {

        HasRequired(o => o.Org)
           .WithMany(o => o.Requests)
           .HasForeignKey(o => o.OrgId);
     }
}
```

Every time I go to make a new Request Instance, and assign an Org to it, it creates a NEW record in the Org table - no matter what. This is on the same dbcontext. I've tried various mappings in the configuration, all result in the same behavior. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must tell EF that the `Org` already exists. Otherwise EF will assume that the `Org` is new and that you want to insert it into the database. Can can do it by either loading the existing `Org` from the database or by attaching it to the context:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var newRequest = new Request();

    var existingOrg = new Org { Id = existingOrgId };
    context.Orgs.Attach(existingOrg);
    // or instead of the previous two lines:
    // var existingOrg = context.Orgs.Find(existingOrgId);

    newRequest.Org = existingOrg;

    context.Requests.Add(newRequest);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This will insert a new `Request` with a foreign key of `OrgId` refering to the existing `Org`.

Actually because you have a foreign key property you don't need an `Org` instance at all. You can just set the FK value:

```
    var newRequest = new Request();

    newRequest.OrgId = existingOrgId;

    context.Requests.Add(newRequest);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Ah yes, was missing the attach from the Orgs side! Thank you!